# How can I define required attributes for the root element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I can't find out how to add a required attribute for my element `shop-offer`. I have tried to place

```
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
```

in the schema root as well as in `<xs:complexType>` of the element but it does not work. I always receive the error that this is not allowed here.

So how can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="shop-offer">

    <xs:complexType mixed="true">

      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="tool">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>      
            </xs:complexType>       
          </xs:element>     
          <xs:element name="widget">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>      
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xs:attribute` declarations are fine, but their placements are requiring the presence of `id` attributes on the `tool` and `widget` elements.

If you also want `id` to be required on the `shop-offer` root element, you'll have to place another just inside the `xs:complexType` (after `xs:sequence`) for `shop-offer`:

**This XSD,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="shop-offer">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="tool">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/> 
            </xs:complexType>                           
          </xs:element>                   
          <xs:element name="widget">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/> 
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>

      <!--  This @id is for the shop-offer root element -->
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/> 

    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**will successfully validate this XML,**

```
<shop-offer id="1">
  <tool id="2"/>
</shop-offer>
```

**as requested.**

---

**Note:** Are you sure that you want `mixed="true"`, which will allow this XML to be valid,

```
<shop-offer id="1">
  Text here.
  <tool id="2"/>
  And more text here.
</shop-offer>
```

perhaps not as desired.